# Oracle ADF Login (works sometimes and redirects to login page itself mostly)

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I have enabled ADF Secruity for my application but I have a weird problem, It hardly logs in in the first attempt. the user will be logged in on a random try sometimes 2 tries or 3 tries or even more. No error message is show it just returns back to the login page. I have implemented logout to kill the session as well but dont know whats going. Do you have any advice to give please.

This is the code I am using with Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3.0:

```
mySubject = Authentication.login(new URLCallbackHandler(un, pw));
ServletAuthentication.runAs(mySubject, request); 
ServletAuthentication.generateNewSessionID(request); 
String loginURL = "/adfAuthentication?success_url=/faces/home.jspx"; 
HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)ctx.getExternalContext().getResponse(); 
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(loginURL); 
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you post also what you've tried so fare, e.g. your related code? Thanks.

Comment: Please post version of software and exact steps and code you tried. Also, if you're new to ADF have you read the docs here: https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/adf/ADFCG/security.htm, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/b31974/adding_security.htm, and viewed the tutorials here:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYbFBeZWjUQ. We would need more detail about the app, the page and the server. ADF has been around for many years and this is a very basic operation, so if ti is not working for you, most likely it is an error or omission on your part.

Comment: Good place to start is here: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/overview/index.html

Comment: Thanks All, This is the code I am using with Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3.0



`mySubject = Authentication.login(new URLCallbackHandler(un, pw));
            ServletAuthentication.runAs(mySubject, request);
            ServletAuthentication.generateNewSessionID(request);
            String loginURL = "/adfAuthentication?success_url=/faces/home.jspx";
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)ctx.getExternalContext().getResponse();
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(loginURL);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);`